# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value (lldb) error

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func savePlayerDetail(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let playerDetailsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? PlayerDetailsViewController {

        //add the new player to the players array
        players.append(playerDetailsViewController.player)

        //update the tableView
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: players.count-1, inSection: 0)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

    }
}
```

// PlayerDetailsViewController I have put prepareForSegue at the bottom to player object.

```
class PlayerDetailsViewController: UITableViewController {

    var player:Player!

    @IBOutlet weak var detailLabel: UITableViewCell!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            nameTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SavePlayerDetail" {
            player = Player(name: self.nameTextField.text, game: "Chess", rating: 1)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to add a new player into a list. But players.append line fatal error. I don't know what it says, please describe me.

Comment: Because your `playerDetailsViewController.player` is `nil`.

Comment: playerDetailsViewController file above, I think that it can be possible in this situation.

Comment: Debug your code and you can find why your player is nil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your `player` property of `playerDetailsViewController` instance. This is an optional and seems to be `nil`

```
IBAction func savePlayerDetail(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let playerDetailsViewController = segue.sourceViewController as? PlayerDetailsViewController {

         if let player = playerDetailsViewController.player{

              //add the new player to the players array
               players.append(player)

              //update the tableView
              let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: players.count-1, inSection: 0)
              tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
         }
         else{

             println("player is empty")
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: "player is empty" I have added new some code at the topic about playerDetailsViewController File, Could you examine that code?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, You have not set `identifier` for `unwind segue` in `Storyboard`.

Set `identifier` to `SavePlayerDetail` when you bind the method `savePlayerDetail` to `Exit` in storyboard.

[image]
Double check this.It may help!

Comment: Recreate all of these segue and it works well, thanks you warn me.